# std::async() does not seem to really implement single-threaded asynchronous behaviour?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

**Context:** I was looking at how asynchronous programming really works. After some investigation on the topic, the resulting idea was that there are two things to differentiate:

- Concurrency (synchronous/asynchronous): About tasks
- Multi-threading: About workers

Based on these concepts, we can identify 4 main ways to parallelize tasks. Better than 100 words, I have made a drawing to illustrate this:

[image]

**Note:** The 4<sup>th</sup> column (*Multi-threaded asynchronous*) will not be considered here since it mixes multi-threading and asynchronous programming.

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), we have the template function [std::async()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to allow us to run a function asynchronously.

We can set the [launch policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) at:

- `std::launch::async`: Run "asynchronously" in a separate thread.
- `std::launch::deferred`: Run when the result is requested.

**Question:** If we take a look at my drawing, the `std::launch::async` policy seems to behave as *Multi-threaded synchronous* and the `std::launch::deferred` policy seems to behave as an isolated case of *Single-threaded asynchronous* (the function is oneshot executed when the result is requested).

But if I'm not mistaken, the idea behind *Single-threaded asynchronous* is that in case of waiting for a resource to be available or when struggling with some latency (disk access time, ...), the program should not keep blocking the main thread (and so wasting time) and go on to do the next task instead (and come back later to the previous one).

What I don't understand is that `std::async()` does not seem to allow this kind of behaviour. We can only either run the task synchronously in another thread or running it once and for all when the result is requested (as late as possible).

If we take a look at my drawing, the *Single-threaded asynchronous* method is not really implemented ***since the function runs in "oneshot" no matter if it will have to wait for a resource or not***. So we will still waste time in this case.

I'm wondering why ? Is my understanding wrong ? Is it an oversight in the `std::async()` implementation or is it intentional (by the standard) ?

---

*<sub>**Edit:** I'm not sure if it is the right place to ask this question since it is not really a "coding" issue/question.</sub>*

Comment: Why do you think that `std::async` implements the "single-threaded asynchronous" pattern?

Comment: I have a problem understanding the difference between multi-thread synchronous and single-thread asynchronous. In both cases every task needs it own stack. So it basicly are three seperate threads. The difference is then reduced to the thread sheduler.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because I assumed `std::async()` was meant for running tasks asynchronously and what I called  _Single-threaded asynchronous_ pattern is a recurrent illustration of the asynchronous operating. I know there are several types of asynchrony (`std::async()` seems to implement two of them), but this pattern was often mentioned with the motivation I wrote in my question. I wanted to know if there is a specific reason to not have implemented it. But indeed, perhaps what I'm looking for through asynchrony is coroutines in reality. Thanks for the notice :)

Comment: @generic_opto_guy The difference is that in _Multi-threading synchronous_, you have 3 workers with one task each one (running simultaneously). In _Single-threaded asynchronous_, you have only one worker with three tasks. The scheduling is up to the worker to choose (but the results must be available when needed). The tasks are not really running simultaneously.

Comment: aysnchronous in this case simply means "not-synchronous" as in "non-blocking" or "don't wait until executed", it doesn't apply any further meaning. Additional launch policies could be added in future standards or as vendor extensions to provide additional semantics

Comment: @AlanBirtles This answers my interrogations.